# How to limit sbt thread number

Tags: sbt

I run command `sbt` failed with error message:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I didn't run the program on my own server, instead it is a server provided by vendor.

The user process number is set to 50, which cannot be changed. It is enough for the building tool like cmake. I don't know how many threads sbt needs.
Is there any way to config sbt's thread number?